# Can't communicate between pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

**Objective:** I'm trying to connect two express apps to communicate with each other.
**Setup:**

- Each app is deployed in a different Pod.
- I'm trying to use a ClusterIP service to make a req from Pod 1 to Pod 2.

Example,

- Say pod 1 has an `axios.post('http://pod-2-clusterip-service:4005', data)`, and
- Pod 2 has ClusterIP service config that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: pod-2-clusterip-service
spec: 
  selector:
   app: pod2
  ports:
    - name: pod2
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4005
      targetPort: 4005
```

Both pods seems to be up and running, when i do kubectl logs i can see that. Problem is, when I run this request from Pod 1 (through postman to NodePort service, i get:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

<ref *1> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.110.68.128:4005
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
```

And the app inside Pod 1 is crashing.

Someone has an Idea what can it be?
I tried restarting the services and pods... didn't help.

**Edit**:
This is what the deployment file look like (event-bus is actually pod2):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: event-bus-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: event-bus 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: event-bus
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: event-bus
          image: dannom/event-bus
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: event-bus-srv
spec: 
  selector:
   app: event-bus
  ports:
    - name: event-bus
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4005
      targetPort: 4005
```

Comment: Is there a Pod with a label `app: pod2`; if you `kubectl describe service pod-2-clusterip-service`, does it say `Endpoints: <none>` (bad) or something else (good)?  Is the application in `pod2` actually listening on 0.0.0.0:4005?

Comment: @DavidMaze hey, it does say Endpoints: <none>. why is it bad and how to solve it?
and yes pod2 is listening on 4005

Comment: `Endpoints: <none>` means the Service's `selector:` doesn't match the Pod's `labels:`.  What does the Deployment for `pod2` look like?

Comment: @DavidMaze i added it to the original question, does it shed any light on the problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint or DNS to connect to your application pod via service would be of the form

`<svc-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

That would in your case would be

`pod-2-clusterip-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Update this based on the above endpoint.

```
axios.post('http://pod-2-clusterip-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:4005', data)
```

**Note:**

- Update namespace with the actual namespace in which your pod and service are deployed.

**Helpful commands:**

- Get Namespaces:

```
kubectl get ns
```

If you haven't created any new namespace, all resources by default are created in a namespace called `default`.

So, `default` can be used in place of `<namespace>`

**Debug Steps:**

- Exec into the pod, and run the following command

```
nslookup pod-2-clusterip-service
```

You will get output containing a Name and its corresponding address.
Use that name. And if the application accessing this service is also in the same namespace only `pod-2-clusterip-service` will also work.

Comment: thank you. what is the namespace exactly? sorry for the novice question. i'm new to docker/k8s

Comment: Namespace in K8s is used to isolate workloads in a single cluster. Like we can group an application its related services into one namespace and another application and its associated components into another. Added information in my answer.

Comment: @Dannom Please mark it as an accepted answer if it solved your issue to mark this question as closed. Thanks.

Comment: so actually it didn't work unfortunately. changed the url to what you said and default as namespace and got the same result.

Comment: attach the output of `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl get svc` in your question.

Comment: The error output shown in the question successfully resolves the host name to the Service's cluster-internal IP address; this doesn't seem like the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So i was only able to resolve the issue by deleting all images and deployments and go through the process from scratch.

If you encounter my problem just follow these steps:

`docker images -a -q` is going to remove all docker images that you have on your PC

`kubectl delete deployment <deployment_name>` deletes deployment

`docker build --no-cache -t <your_tag>/pod1 .` is going to create an image without any precached stuff.

`docker push <your_tag>/pod1` pushes to docker image storage

`kubectl apply pod1-depl.yaml` start deployment